# Altitude data for european highways

Tags: geospatial, uses-of-open-data, europe

Are there publicly available altitude data for the major european highways? I need the altitudes on the road surface, not in the surrounding area. I believe that the open DEM files (or SRTM data) shows the "bare earth" and they are not suitable for my needs. LiDAR data might be a good candidate but I cannot find public data for the whole of Europe

Comment: Are you sure DEM files don't include road elevations? I've downloaded DEM files for my city, and the highways are clearly visible as being higher than the surrounding terrain

Comment: I am not 100% sure. I just checked (visually) a couple of roads that I know they are elevated and the DEM I used had the same altitude on the road surface and on the surrounding area. Also, a major bridge was completely missing. Anyway, I will try some DEMs from other sources. Thanks!